# querystring to json in classic asp

Tags: json, asp-classic, query-string

i'm a beginner in Classic ASP and this is my first question in stackoverflow... i need to transform a query string, with a random number of parameters in json:

```
param1=hi&param2=hello&param3=byebye....  paramN=gudnight
```

in something like this:

```
{"param1":"hi","param2":"hello","param3":"byebye"...,"paramN":"gudnight"}
```

is there something to do this automatically in asp??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server" src="http://www.JSON.org/json2.js"></script>

<%
    DIM jsonQueryString
    SET jsonQueryString = JSON.parse("{}")

    For Each item In Request.QueryString
        DIM key : key = Request.QueryString.Key(item)
        DIM val : val = Request.QueryString(key)(1)
        jsonQueryString.set key, val
    Next

    Response.Write JSON.stringify(jsonQueryString)
%>
```

UPDATE: The json2.js file included is a json parser class but it is no longer at that location.  We downloaded a copy of it which is on our servers and we currently use.  You can find an up to date copy of it at the following url - https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.

So if I hit my test page with the following url -

```
http://localhost:8080/tests/ws/parsequerytojson.asp?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

I get the following JSON formatted response -

```
{
    a: "1",
    b: "2",
    c: "3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to set all this parameters Dictionary, then Serialize it with  JavaScriptSerializer.
Example:

```
public string ConvertParametersToJson(Dictionary<string, string> queryParameters)
{
   var dic = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.ToDictionary<string, string, object>(key => key, key => Request.QueryString[key]);
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };
   var json = serializer.Serialize(dic);
   return json;
}
```

Comment: i already know that solution in C#, i need it in ASP. is there something like that for ASP? ty...

Comment: What do you mean in ASP? ASP.net is framework. You can write codebehind using one of .net languages for example using c#. Could you  add more information what you want to do.

Comment: Classic Asp... It was so long ago. I don't remember it. Sorry.